# alignItems: center prevents flex row text wrapping in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

For some reason, setting `alignItems: center` in the style on the container view causes text inside a flex row to stop wrapping, and to not respect the container view's `padding`.

Working example and code here: https://rnplay.org/apps/FsDXuQ

I tried following the advice to [set flexDirection to column](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1438), [use flex: 1 or flexWrap](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/901) but the only thing that works is removing the `alignItems: center` from the container view.

I don't understand what's going on here. What if I want:

1. Row elements, which don't take up the full width of the screen,
2. Centered,
3. With long text inside them,
4. Which wraps?

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] **in the question itself.** This will help the Stack Overflow community by clarifying the problem, and survive if / when your linked example goes offline.

Answer (score 7):

Use `flex` property. Ex.`<Text style={{ flex: 1}}>`

Answer (score 3):

We ran into this same problem at my company, and as far as I am aware, there is no non hacky way around it.

The way we handled it was to remove the alignItems property from the main container completely, and give the container a flex:1 property. We then used alignItems: 'center' to any child component we needed, without the style being spread to all child components.

I've set up an example of what I'm talking about [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/RP3XbQ), and pasted the code below.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions
} = React;

var width = Dimensions.get('window').width

var shortText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis.";
var longText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin ligula ut leo dictum, id elementum sapien faucibus. Nullam et feugiat neque";

var SampleApp = React.createClass({ 
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={ styles.alignCenter }>
            <Text>{shortText}</Text>
             </View>
        <Text/>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
          <Image source={{uri: "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-male-avatars/128/Male-Avatar-icon.png"}} style={{height: 32, width: 32}}/>
          <View style={{ flex:1 }}>
          <Text >{longText}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
       </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    padding: 30,
    marginTop: 65,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flex:1
    },
  alignCenter: {
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: Thanks. I agree that in the specific case this works, but I think it doesn't completely solve the problem I posed: if you want the text elements to be centered in the view, _and_ you want the text to wrap. This doesn't seem to be possible, unless I'm missing something. Example: https://rnplay.org/apps/NVZPwQ

Answer (score 3):

Been doing searching of my own to fix this:

```
textStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
}
```

Courtesy of this article: http://moduscreate.com/aligning-children-using-flexbox-in-react-native/

Get rid of any `alignItems` in direct parents to allow the flexWrap to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to do a little more than @trik indicated.

I also had to remove alignItems: 'center' from the container (parent component).

I also found that if I needed the container to use alignItems: 'center', then I  had to set the width of my child component to be large enough to accommodate the text as well as use textAlign: 'center'.

This would use styles similar to the following:

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export default StyleSheet.create({
  centeredParent: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  centeredChild: {
    width: '100%',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

**BONUS TIP:** If you set the background of a text component to a contrasting color, then you can see the box for the text component.  This makes debugging these issues easier.